# How to get time taken by the insertion to sqlite in milliseconds

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my code :

```
NSLog(@"Insert time before = %f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
[self insertDataInSqlite]; 
NSLog(@"Insert time after = %f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
```

but i want to print time taken by this insert method.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"start time:%@", NSDate.date);
[self insertDataInSqlite];
NSLog(@"end time:%@", NSDate.date);
```

This would be the easiest way to see the insertion time.